# find file in subfolder, move to other directory, and delete subfolder after moving with find -exec

Tags: bash, find, exec

I am looking for the following:
I want to search files with .m4a in all subfolders in my directory. When a file with this ending was found, I would like to move it to another folder. But afterwards I would like to delete this subfolder. I am stuck with the last step. 
So far I have:

```
    find . -name '*.m4a' -type f -exec mv {} /path/to/storage \;
```

I don't know how to delete the subfolder, the m4a file was found in. Also I don't want to delete by accident any other folder (I mean in case I apply the rm command wrongly. Deleting a subfolder, where I found a m4a file in, is okay). Basically, I am not sure how to control the deleting and would I be able to add this command with another -exec in the find command, please?
Thank you!

Comment: what is the benefit of moving to folder, why don't just delete a file at once?

Comment: Do you mean you want to delete the original folder?

Comment: I wish to select in a subfolder a file with the ending m4a. Push this into a collecting folder, delete the rest content of the subfolder and delete the subfolder. I don't want to delete the m4a file, but the the remaining files in this folder after having moved the selected file out of it.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should be ok.

If you are happy with the results, you can remove the echo to perform real actions:

```
find . -name '*.m4a' -type f -exec sh -c 'echo "mv {} /path/to/storage";echo "rm -r "$(dirname {})"" ' \;
```

Be carefull that if the /path/to/storage is a subdirectory under the current working working you performed find, will also be removed , like this:

```
$ pwd
/home/gv/Desktop/PythonTests/tmp/tmp2
$ find . -name 'test.txt' -exec sh -c 'echo "mv {} /home/gv/Desktop/PythonTests/tmp/tmp2";echo "rm -r "$(dirname {})"" ' \;
mv ./tmp3/test.txt /home/gv/Desktop/PythonTests/tmp/tmp2  #indeed test.txt was in subfolder tmp3 under cwd tmp2
rm -r ./tmp3  #this is good - file moved , tmp3 removed also
mv ./test.txt /home/gv/Desktop/PythonTests/tmp/tmp2  #oops. find returned the result after previous mv , now file is found under tmp2
rm -r .  #tmp2 gone also!
```

Comment: George, thank you for your help. The storage path is not a subfolder. I tried your command without the echo and removing ' ', but I receive:
find: -exec: no terminating ";" or "+"
rm: "." and ".." may not be removed
rm: ;: No such file or directory                                                                                        I will try to figure out why it does not work.

Comment: I also want to point out that -exec rm -r $(dirname {}) translates into the current directory of ".". But this does not seem to be the subfolder-directory.
I am still unable to delete the subfolder, moving works. But of course I don't want to delete by accident the top-level directory nor my hard drive.

Comment: I tried it for several hours now, but I ended up using a good old for loop. Sorry about this.
The code looks like this now                                                     SAVEIFS=$IFS
IFS=$(echo -en "\n\b")

for i in `find . -name "*.m4a"`
do

filename="$(basename $i)"
#echo $filename

subfolderpath="$(dirname $i)"
#echo $subfolderpath

mv "$subfolderpath/$filename" "$targetdirectory/"

rm -r $subfolderpath
done

Comment: @Gudrun Are you sure that this one does not work for you? Seems to work fine for me: `find . -name 'test.txt' -exec sh -c 'mv {} /home/gv/Desktop/PythonTests/tmp/tmp2;rm -r "$(dirname {})" ' \;`

Comment: Yes, this does not work. Command: find /toplevel/folder/to/be/searched -name "*.m4a" -exec sh -c 'mv {} /path/to/storage/folder; rm -r "$(dirname {})" ' \;                                                                                                                                      Error message: sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('                        Although, this is now another error message, before I got that rm is unable to remove "." and "..". Maybe it is important that I run on 10.12.4 iOSX.